# How to Use Parametric Bootstrap to Calculate Covariance Matrix?

Tags: r, variance

Using the following dataset "data": `load(url("https://www.math.ntnu.no/emner/TMA4315/2020h/hoge-veluwe.Rdata"))` 
I have fit a poisson GLM `model = glm(y~t + I(t^2), family = poisson, data)`. I now want to estimate the covariance matrix of the β coefficients obtained from the GLM regression by using parametric bootstrapping with 1000 simulations. My code so far is:

```
ysim = simulate(mod_quad, 1)
betahat = matrix(0,nrow = 1000, ncol = 3)
for (i in 1:1000){  
  sim_data = cbind(ysim, data$t)
  betahat[i, ]= glm(ysim ~ data$t + I(data$t^2), 
family = poisson, 
data = sim_data )$coefficients
  ysim = simulate(glm(ysim ~ data$t + I(data$t^2)family = poisson, data = sim_data ), 1)
}

var(betahat[1000,])
```

The betahat matrix just comes out to a zero matrix each time so I'm not sure what is missing in my approach?

Answer (score 2):

This is really more of a coding than a statistical question. Streamlining, I would do this:

```
## set vals to NA (not 0) to make detection of problems easier
betahat <- matrix(NA, nrow = 1000, ncol = 3)
for (i in 1:1000) {
    ## replace response with parametric simulation
    sim_data <- transform(data, y=simulate(mod_quad, 1)[[1]])
    ## refit model with new data
    newfit <- update(mod_quad, data=sim_data)
    ## store new coefficients
    betahat[i, ] <- coef(newfit) 
}
## compute variance
var(betahat)
```